# Publishing with JBOSS Tools Indigo Skips web.xml

Tags: maven, jboss, publish, web.xml

I am migrating from JBOSS 6 to JBOSS 7.  The migration itself was incredibly easy.  However, I am experiencing problems with developer environment integration.  Here is my problem:

When I was on JBOSS 6, I was on publishing through Helios and all was well.  I could not upgrade my JBOSS tools to recognize JBOSS AS 7, so I upgraded my version of eclipse as well.  The JBOSS 7 server was recognized no problem.  Starting and stopping the server is also no problem.  Building (with maven) through eclipse and manually deploying (copy/paste of the .war file) also works fine.  However, with 1 of my projects, publishing through eclipse (right click on server, add/remove) does not work.  The web.xml file is not published to the WEB-INF folder.  This causes a "successful" deploy, but with no web.xml, the application does not work and is essentially a file server.  There are no errors shown.

I will point out that I do not believe the problem has to do with JBOSS 7.  I tried the same publish process above for JBOSS 6 (the server I was migrating from and still works when publishing from helios) with the same result.  I have also tried manually adding the web.xml to the deployed applications WEB-INF folder, and the application does deploy successfully that way.

I have 3 projects total in the workspace.  2 are publishing properly through the JBOSS AS interface in eclipse (including web.xml).  The projects are a RESTeasy webservice (working), a jsp servlet (working), a JSF application (not working).  All use spring and hibernate (in case that is relevant).

Does anyone know what could possibly cause the web.xml to not be included in the published (exploded) war folder?

Please let me know if you would like me to include any specific files.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. All files auto deployed except web.xml. Eventually I copied the contents of web.xml, deleted it in Eclipse and created the file again. Then JBoss tools picked up the file and deployed it as expected.